# How to pass Hex values to a string - Android

Tags: java, android

I need to create a String from hex values I'm providing.

For example, instead of assigning like this:

```
String message = "123";
```

I want to assign like this:

```
String message = 0x31, 0x32, 0x33;
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably also specify the character set you are using but this will do it:

```
String message = new String(new byte[] {0x31, 0x32, 0x33});
System.out.println(message); // prints 123.
```

If you did want to specify the character set it is just another parameter to the `String` constructor. The following example will work if targeting Android API 19+:

```
String message = new String(new byte[] {0x31, 0x32, 0x33}, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: you definitely should specify the encoding relevant to that byte sequence. By default it will be utf-8, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `String` representation of a Hex value (say, you are getting the value from the server, in a JSON object), you might need to make sure to treat it as a Hex value. You can import `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;` and then do this:

```
String stringHex = "a37e7391ebbc939a8489788d93015914eeee423132e2516711e81d53777067ee"
String yourString = new String(Hex.decodeHex(stringHex.toCharArray()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Just wanted to add to the above answer.